# How to rotate a PDF file using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

I'm trying to rotate a PDF file using ruby (e.g. 90 or 180 degrees). I'm using ImageMagick currently, however the issue I'm facing is that the quality of the output file drops a lot.

Here it is a sample code:

```
new_image = Magick::Image.read(image_path).first
new_image = new_image.rotate(degrees)
new_image.write(image_path)
```

Do you know what technic/tool/library should be used in order to not lose any quality after rotating a PDF.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using SVG for transformations? You could translate your PDF to SVG using Inkscape

```
inkscape -l out.svg in.pdf
```

Then add rotation in SVG [using the `transform` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) and covert it back to PDF

```
inkscape -A out.pdf in.svg
```

I realise that you've asked for a solution in Ruby, but in case you won't find any this might help to solve the problem.