# Rotate a pdf in ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf, imagemagick, prawn

I'm using prawn to create a pdf file. In some cases, after the generation, I need to change the pdf orientation from landscape to portrait.

Prawn provide a `rotate` function but it do not apply to the whole pdf and for some reasons, the rotation must be done after / at the end of the generation.

I found [this solution with ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388544/how-to-rotate-a-pdf-file-using-ruby) but I'm also facing huge quality drops (and no solution was provided).

I also tried to use my generated pdf as a template for a new prawn pdf and to use `:page_layout` to change the orientation :

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(page_layout: :landscape, template: file_name)
pdf.render
```

But the `template` parameter seem to be ignored and it just creating a blank pdf.

I'm looking for a good solution (bonus point if I don't need external library).

Answer (score 6):

You can look into the [`combine_pdf` gem](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) (spoiler: I'm the author)...

... Although I think you'll experience better performance by setting the correct layout beforehand (you'll avoid the need to parse the PDF in a different tool if you manage it within Prawn).

You can try something to the effect of:

```
# get the PDF data from prawn and parse it
pdf = CombinePDF.parse prawn_pdf.render
# rotate everything that needs rotation clockwise
pdf.pages.each {|p| p.orientation :landscape }
# or, counter-clockwise:
pdf.pages.each {|p| p.orientation :landscape, false }
# export to String
pdf.to_pdf
# write to file
pdf.save 'my.pdf'
```

Good luck.

Comment: `page.rotate_180` was exactly what I needed. ;)

Comment: for me it was page.rotate_left